# Where can I add core <item> elements with Views RSS

Tags: views, feeds

I'm trying to set up a podcast feed with Views RSS. I think I've succesfully [set up the module](https://drupal.org/node/1346494) and the [core <channel> elements](https://drupal.org/node/1346496).

I am now trying to set up the core <item> elements, as explained [here](https://drupal.org/node/1346498). However, I have no idea if I'm looking in the correct place.

I go to `admin/structure/views/view/gentle_podcast/edit/feed_1` and under `Format` I see:

- Format: RSS Feed | Settings
- Display: Fields | Settings

(I'm translating from Dutch, so labels may be off). When I click the Settings next to Display, I get a popup where I can set Title, Link, Description, Creator, Publication date and Guid.

How can I set all the other items that the documentation mentions?

Does it check the fields I've added to the view? Because I've added a field that has the URL of my podcast file (an mp3), but I don't see anywhere to set the <enclosure> item.

You can see the current result of my view [here (as feed)](http://gentlesite.be/drupal/podcast.xml) and [here (as page)](http://gentlesite.be/drupal/podcast).

Comment: Can you clarify which version of views (2.x or 3.x?) and Drupal you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing a couple things. First, make sure that you have the Views RSS: Core Elements submodule enabled -- this is what allows you access to the many other fields. This may already be enabled and if so, the reason you're not seeing the fields is that you need to switch your format to RSS Feed - Fields, ex:

[image]

by clicking the 'RSS Feed' link in your Format Settings.

Now, when you adjust the settings for this, you'll see the options for the item elements you were looking for.

[image]

You'll need to add the appropriate fields from your content to have them appear in the select lists.

Comment: Thanks. I had the module enabled, but the Format was on RSS Feed, not RSS Feed - Fields. Stup how I overlooked that.